# Unable to process file error with maven-dependency-analyzer

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform, maven-dependency-plugin

`mvn dependency:analyze` on my project is unable to process files (see log below). I can't understand why, the compilation seems OK since I can run the application fine.

The parent pom.xml configures `maven.compiler.plugin.version=3.10.0` with `release=17`, and `-Xlint:all` as compiler arguments.

Repo is available [here](https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLabTemp). The log was used on project `modules/Phrase`, but all the modules have the same problem. Win10, cygwin, JDK17, and I'm a beginner in Maven...

```
$ mvn dependency:analyze -Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-phrase >--------------------
[INFO] Building Phrase 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ nbm ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> dependency:2.8:analyze (default-cli) > test-compile @ org-jjazz-phrase >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ org-jjazz-phrase ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.0:compile (default-compile) @ org-jjazz-phrase ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- nbm:4.8:manifest (default-manifest) @ org-jjazz-phrase ---
[INFO] NBM Plugin generates manifest
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ org-jjazz-phrase ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\JeromeDocs\NetBeansProjects\JJazzLab\modules\Phrase\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ org-jjazz-phrase ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< dependency:2.8:analyze (default-cli) < test-compile @ org-jjazz-phrase <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency:2.8:analyze (default-cli) @ org-jjazz-phrase ---
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.CyclicPositions
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.Grid
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.NoteEvent$AsNoteKey
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.NoteEvent
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.Phrase$6
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.Phrase
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.Phrases
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.PhraseSamples
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.SizedPhrase
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.SourcePhrase
Unable to process: org.jjazz.phrase.api.SourcePhraseSet
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.6-jre:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-guava:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-chordleadsheet:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-midi:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.netbeans.api:org-openide-dialogs:jar:RELEASE170:compile
[WARNING]    org.netbeans.api:org-openide-util:jar:RELEASE170:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.754 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-21T16:24:36+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 4 plugin(s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.12.1
[WARNING]   Plugin issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Plugin depends on the deprecated Maven 2.x compatibility layer, which may not be supported in Maven 4.x
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0
[WARNING]   Declared at location(s):
[WARNING]    * org.jjazzlab:jjazzlab-parent:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Jerome\.m2\repository\org\jjazzlab\jjazzlab-parent\1.0-SNAPSHOT\jjazzlab-parent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom) @ line 35
[WARNING]   Used in module(s):
[WARNING]    * org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-phrase:1.0-SNAPSHOT (pom.xml)
[WARNING]   Plugin issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Plugin should declare these Maven artifacts in `provided` scope: [org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:
maven-settings:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:3.2.5, org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:3.2.5, o
rg.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.2.5]
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.netbeans.utilities:nbm-maven-plugin:4.8
[WARNING]   Declared at location(s):
[WARNING]    * org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-phrase:1.0-SNAPSHOT (pom.xml) @ line 16
[WARNING]   Used in module(s):
[WARNING]    * org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-phrase:1.0-SNAPSHOT (pom.xml)
[WARNING]   Plugin issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Plugin depends on the deprecated Maven 2.x compatibility layer, which may not be supported in Maven 4.x
[WARNING]    * Plugin depends on plexus-container-default, which is EOL
[WARNING]   Mojo issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Mojo nbm:manifest (org.apache.netbeans.nbm.NetBeansManifestUpdateMojo)
[WARNING]      - Parameter 'localRepository' uses deprecated parameter expression '${localRepository}': ArtifactRepository type is deprecated and its use in Mojos should be avoided.
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8
[WARNING]   Declared at location(s):
[WARNING]    * unknown
[WARNING]   Used in module(s):
[WARNING]    * org.jjazzlab:org-jjazz-phrase:1.0-SNAPSHOT (pom.xml)
[WARNING]   Plugin issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Plugin is a Maven 2.x plugin, which will be not supported in Maven 4.x
[WARNING]    * Plugin depends on plexus-container-default, which is EOL
[WARNING]   Mojo issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Mojo dependency:analyze (org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.analyze.AnalyzeMojo)
[WARNING]      - Implements `Contextualizable` interface from Plexus Container, which is EOL.
[WARNING]
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Fix reported issues by adjusting plugin configuration or by upgrading above listed plugins. If no upgrade available, please notify plugin maintainers about reported issues.
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING]
```

Comment: please try with the latest dependency plugin version `mvn dependency:3.5.0:analyze`

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue, you can post the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of the dependency plugin.
Add this to the pluginManagement section of your pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```